# What's arxiv “endorsement” policy?

Tags: publications, arxiv

[arxiv](http://arxiv.org) has an endorsement system, where

> during the submission process, we may require authors who are submitting papers to an archive or subject class for the first time to get an endorsement from another arXiv author

However, I submitted a paper to arxiv for the first time, and I was not asked for an endorsement. The [relevant help page](http://arxiv.org/help/endorsement) says:

> During the initial deployment of the system, we may also give automatic endorsements to submitters from known academic institutions.

So this may be what happened to me (I have a verified email address from an academic institution), but this seems weird, because it says *“during the initial deployment of the system”*, and this is dated **2004**.

So: does someone know what is the *current* endorsement policy for arxiv?

Comment: You are quoting a *current* page and ask what the current policy is?

Comment: *We may give some people automatic endorsements based on topic, previous submissions, and academic affiliation.*

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham I am asking if someone who has experience with arxiv knows in more detail how endorsements work. The page is thoroughly unclear: 1. it says they *may* require endorsement (but do not say how the decision is made); 2. academic affiliation is cited twice, once saying “during initial deployment” (making it clear the page wasn't updated since 2004), once without mention of temporal restriction (but again with the *may*, and no stated criterion).

Comment: They are being deliberately vague, to give themselves flexibility.  For example, some departments are very lax about making people unpaid visiting scholars.  That's justifiable: it often offers nothing but library privileges, and one can make a case that it's good to extend library access to just about anyone, even crackpots.  However, it's not clear that arXiv posting should be treated similarly.  If the arXiv promised that academic affiliation always guaranteed an endorsement, then they would have to explain what counts as a "real" academic affiliation and why.  It's easiest to be vague.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician to be fair, there's plenty of crackpot content on arxiv anyway, even with these rules in place :)

Comment: Incidentally, I view the vagueness as a feature, rather than a bug.  The downside is that it allows a small potential for abuse of the endorsement system, but I've never heard of it causing problems for anything I'd consider to be legitimate research.  The upside is that the vagueness protects the arXiv from an endless stream of legalistic complaints from people outside of mainstream research.

Comment: Regarding the crackpot content, that's true.  There's a trade-off here, where you want to minimize the junk without actually causing a burden for anything serious.  I imagine that completely eliminating all crackpot papers would require a slower, more intrusive, or more error-prone system for everyone else.  :-/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe the help page describes the current endorsement policy.  You may also have fallen into the category described by "We may give some people automatic endorsements based on topic, previous submissions, and academic affiliation."

As I understand it, most people are in that category and never see the endorsement system in action.  In practice, it seems to get applied to cranks and to people who look like they might possibly be cranks (e.g., people with no academic affiliation, or who are writing on controversial topics).

Comment: This is also my experience.

Comment: Some people (having affiliation) submit using their webmail id, endorsement is required in that case. Some universities do not yet provide official email ids.