# How to obtain an alpha-numeric endorsement code to give to my potential arXive endorser

Tags: arxiv

How to I obtain an alpha-numeric passcode for my potential arxiv endorser

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  Can you please provide some more context on your question?  I've published on arXiv before, but I'm afraid that I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: If (and only if) you have an endorser, then you can upload a manuscript to arxiv (and not before). Otherwise you cannot upload an article and thus there is nothing to give to anyone else (the one you refer to as "potential arxiv endorser").

Comment: Have you tried to register first?  I presume it is given to you either at that stage or when you first try to submit.  See also: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/4812/19607

Answer (score 1):

Whether you will need an endorsement code or not depends (among other things) to which category you submit to, which suggests that you will be given an endorsement code during the submission process (if necessary). The [help page](http://arxiv.org/help/endorsement) also mentions "during the submission process".