# Should an undergraduate claim ownership of their article uploaded on arXiv?

Tags: publications, authorship, arxiv

As an undergraduate, I wrote a paper with a professor in the physics department. He has uploaded the paper to arXiv, and he forwarded me the email that he (automatically) received upon submitting the article. Part of it states:

> A paper password will be emailed to you when the article is announced. 
>   You should share this with co-authors to allow them to claim ownership.

Does this mean that, even as an undergraduate, I should create an account on arXiv (not sure if possible) and claim co-ownership of the article?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it means. (I'm an arXiv moderator.)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Congratulations on your paper!

You don't have to, but it would be a good idea to make an arXiv account and use it to claim ownership of the paper.  This will make it easier for people to find your work when searching by your name, and vice versa.  It will also establish an account that you can use for any future papers you write.

The fact that you're an undergraduate is irrelevant; arXiv doesn't care.  In fact anybody at all can create an arXiv account.  In order to actually submit an article, there is an [endorsement](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4812/whats-arxiv-endorsement-policy) process, but that's not really important here: endorsement isn't needed to claim ownership of a paper submitted by someone else (and presumably your co-author is already endorsed).

Comment: And this changes nothing in the long run. Assuming I go to graduate school and then join academia, I could update the account (email, affiliations etc.) accordingly and still continue to use this account dating back to my undergraduate days?

Comment: @JunaidAftab: Yes, certainly you can.

Comment: The fact that your professor forwarded that email to you, means that he expects/encourages you to claim co-authorship.

Comment: Seems that most important thing is in the comment by @MaartenBuis - OP *should* do it, because it costs nothing and his professor expects it. Meeting reasonable expectations of professors is a good thing you usually should do.

Comment: When I make suggestions like that, then I do that to help the student. I don't want them to do it because I told them so, but because it helps them. As such I am by no means personally offended when they don't do it, I just regret the missed opportunity for them.

Comment: @MaartenBuis: I wouldn't necessarily read that into it.  The professor may have just forwarded the email as a way to show OP that the preprint had been successfully submitted.  The note about claiming authorship is part of the automatic email; the professor might not even have noticed it was there.  So I don't see this as the professor *telling* OP to do it.  But I am suggesting that it's a good idea in any case.

Comment: @Nate (1 comment up) Technically I suppose so, but I would find it quite unlikely that a professor would forward the email without expecting the student to use the paper password to claim the article.