# Does first-time submission need endorsement even if the author is affiliated

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv

On the [endorsement page](https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement) of Arxiv, it says "During the submission process, however, we may require authors who are submitting papers to a subject category for the first time to get an endorsement from an established arXiv author". Does this mean that the first-time submission still needs endorsement even if the author is affiliated with an institution?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what that text says? I don't understand what's unclear.

Comment: Yes, it was copied exactly from the endorsement page of Arxiv.

Comment: The text says "we may require authors who are submitting papers to a subject category for the first time to get an endorsement", so that's what it means. "may" indicates some but not all cases, otherwise they'd write "always" or "never". I don't think they mean to be dodgy or unclear here, this is their official page describing what endorsement means.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4812/whats-arxiv-endorsement-policy?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might do, but it also may not. I submitted my first paper to arXiv 2 months ago, and did not need any endorsement, just signed in with my institutional email.